# Android error : No such method for getDefinedWebViewPackageName

Tags: android, webview

I'm getting an error that says;

```
/com.myapp,name E/WebViewFactory: No such method for getDefinedWebViewPackageName: 
     java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getDefinedWebViewPackageName []
```

This error appears in `Logcat` and as far as I know it doesn't' effect the run of the application.

- What is this error? and
- How can we get rid of it?

For the Webview The JavaScriptis enabled by

```
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

And, the test device is Android One working with version 8.1

Comment: interesting googling: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27285

Comment: @Blundell that is about `webview_flutter`. It may not have the same exact code.

Answer (score 2):

As you directly can not know which method or line of code using getDefinedWebViewPackageName and giving exception. try to figure out if there is any third party library using this. because in my case razorpay checkout preload method was using this :

```
 checkout.preload(getContext().getApplicationContext());
```

in Fragment and getContext() method was returning null context and due to this I was **getting Android error : No such method for getDefinedWebViewPackageName.**
for this I called above line of code in onAttach method of fragment as :

```
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    checkout.preload(context);
}
```

this solved the issue.