# I am getting the error 'WebViewFactory: No such method' in my signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

When i run the app in debug mode it works fine. But when i build the released apk for my app, it gives me the error of WebViewFactory.I don't have any webview in my app. The error is shown below

`2020-01-26 15:41:50.757 29072-29072/com.muhana.uniwork E/WebViewFactory: No such method for 
    getDefinedWebViewPackageName: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getDefinedWebViewPackageName []`

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? If so, what was it? If not, can  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70485053/2597758 help?

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be due to proguard application on your release apk. Even if you are not using webview explicitly, you might have used some library that is using webview internally. Look for proguard rules of the libraries that you have used and add these rules to your project.

Comment: I am using Apache POI library and AdMob. Does admob use WebView?

Comment: You can check proguard rules for respective libraries under their Github Repositories.