# No such method for getDefinedWebViewPackageName:java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:getDefinedWebViewPackageName creating a notification in android studio

Tags: android, notifications

```
    public void notify_please(String text, int rawid){
    Uri introURI = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.skyma.taskme/" + rawid);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setContentText("You have to do the task written below");
    builder.setContentText(text);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
    builder.setSound(introURI);
    long[] vibrate ={100,500,100,500,100,500};
    builder.setVibrate(vibrate);
    //notification message will get at NotificationView
    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

while I am running my function like this :-
notify_please("Noting to do",R.raw.sms_drums);

please give any solution logs are coming like this:-

`2021-04-28 12:11:36.601 20147-20147/com.skyma.taskme E/WebViewFactory: No such method for getDefinedWebViewPackageName: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getDefinedWebViewPackageName []`

My gradle scripts are here

````
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0'

}```


There is default config in my gradle file

Please give me any solution regarding this I want it please as fast as possible.
````

Answer (score 0):

Since without more information we cannot know which is the root cause, I'll share the troubleshooting steps.

1. Find the class where the method is missing.
2. Look for the method `getDefinedWebViewPackageName`. Probably it doesn't exist or, if you are calling from a library, it has been removed with a new version of the library.
3. Check your dependencies

Comment: Hi i can give you more details as you want

Comment: Where do you call the method getDefinedWebViewPackageName? And if it is your own method, where do you have defined it?

Comment: I am getting this error, too. There is no `getDefinedWebViewPackageName` in my source code (I grep-ed it entirely) and Logcat suggests that it is related to `WebViewFactory` which is also nowhere to be found in my source code. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70485053/2597758) seems to have a workaround.